# Programmatically bill PayPal for a recurring payment

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

How to **programmatically** (not manually with our PayPal dashboard) bill (every month) a PayPal subscriber of our service for a non-fixed-amount Automatic Billing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend PayPal's Reference Transactions to achieve your purpose. Please check below link for its details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: There is written there "NVP/SOAP (Deprecated)". Do you recommend a deprecated API? If not, what to use instead? (docs URL?)

Answer (score 0):

The Classic APIs aren't going away for a long time.  They have way too many solutions currently integrated with it, and the newer REST APIs do not currently support all the features that Classic does.  For example, reference transactions are not currently supported in the REST API, so you'll have to use Classic for what you want as of today anyway.  They have said they'll be adding reference transactions to REST sometime this year, but I've heard that about other things before and it generally takes longer than planned.

I am personally sticking with Classic for most of my applications as of today.

Comment: Do you have an example of billing a recurring payment using the classic API's? I've tried and can't get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67254145/68936